# Fluent NHibernate Many to One / One to One

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have Users and Videos and I want to see users videos under user class, and videos user in video class; I don't know how to fill videos of user to that users class and videos user under video class.

Mappings >

```
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Map(x => x.Type);

        HasMany(x => x.Videos);
    }

    public VideoMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.VideoId);

        Map(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.VideoTypeId);
        Map(x => x.Status);
        Map(x => x.Image);

        HasOne(x => x.User)
    }
```

Classes >

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual int Type { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public virtual int VideoId { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual int VideoTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Method >

```
    public static IList<Entities.Video.Video> All()
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            IList<Entities.Video.Video> videos = session.Query<Entities.Video.Video>(
                .Where(C => C.User.UserId == C.UserId).ToList();

            return videos;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your model class you should use IList rather than List. 
and try with mappings

```
public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Map(x => x.Type);
        HasMany(x => x.Videos).KeyColumn("keyColumn");
    }

public VideoMap()
{
    Id(x => x.VideoId);

    Map(x => x.UserId);
    Map(x => x.VideoTypeId);
    Map(x => x.Status);
    Map(x => x.Image);

    References(x => x.User).Column("keyColumn");
}
```

where keyColumn is primary key of your table that contains videos.

and to get videos of user something like this

```
IList<Video> videos = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Video)).CreateAlias("User", "user").Add(Restrictions.Eq("user.UserId", id)).List<Video>().ToList();
```